# Unable to install Wine for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, wine

I tried `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel` but it shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Unable to locate package winehq-devel
```

Comment: Then you do not have the wine repository, it is at the winehq website.

Comment: How about just install the "wine"package?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install wine`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the development version of Wine is not in the vanilla repository *(for obvious reason — it is unstable)*, you have to add its PPA. [Quoting the original page](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

> Add the repository:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
> ```
>
> Update packages list:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Then install (example for the development branch):
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
> ```